# Nativescript placeholder-color style on TextField doesn't work

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How can I set the `placeholder-color` on a `TextField` in Nativescript (6.1.2) with Angular and nativescript-theme-core (2.0.24)?

I've tried setting *_app-common.scss*

```
TextField {
  placeholder-color: red;
}
```

but that doesn't work.

This playground with angular works however: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=x9Gf79&v=2 but it has another file structure than my project.

It also works if I do this instead:

```
.input {
  placeholder-color: red;
}
```

I also found some variables that I tried to override that didn't work either:
*_app-variables.scss*

```
$text-field-hint-color: red !default;
$placeholder-color: red !default;
```

Why doesen't it work when I try to style the `TextField`? And what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I guess it's the precedence, specific class rule takes more precedence than a tag.

Answer (score 1):

@jarrodwhitley have reason is working implementing like this:

```
<TextField style="placeholder-color:white" [(ngModel)]="userName" hint="User Name..." color="white">
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, in Svelte Native based on NativeScript, I can define the property placeholder-color as part of the CSS style for textField, i.e:

```
<textField hint="write something" .../>

<style>
textField {
placeholder-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

It also works inline with `style="placeholder-color:grey"`.

Finally, the following setup also works:

```
<textField hint="write something" class="test" .../>

<style>
.test {
placeholder-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

So Nativescript placeholder-color style for TextField works now, at least through Svelte Native.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't super clear, but looking at the documentation it appears that `placeholder-color` is a "Root View CSS Class". Meaning, you wouldn't set it directly on the text field itself, but on the top-level view which contains it.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#user-interface-styling

I would have totally expected that it would need to be set on the element that I was trying to style. I suspect that this means that all text fields within a given view have to have the same styling.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think that is right? Since I was able to set it directly on the `TextField` in the playground example. I think that's how it should work but maybe it's something with the newer version of Nativescript or nativescript-theme-core.

Comment: I'm able to use `placeholder-color` directly on the `TextField` selector.